# Parse - enable to login via email after updating to version 1.8.2

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

I have an app using Parse. 
It worked perfectly till I update the parse SDK to version 1.8.2
now every time I try to login a user via email
I am getting an Error in the Xcode log saying -

> [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 14.046113 seconds.

and then I get this error:

> (Code: 0, Version: 1.8.2)
>   the error object contains all user information.

Any ideas on what I could be overlooking that would cause this?
I don't believe I changed anything.
This problem occurs on both the simulator and an actual device.

Comment: Have you figured this out?